# How to display the "Share Wi-Fi" QR Code from android network configuration?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, wifi

How can I, programmatically (Kotlin or Java), display the QR Code "Share Wi-Fi" from the currently connected network?

[image: Network details screen.]

The closest I could come was to display the network settings:

`startActivity( Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS) )`

Maybe there are some 'ACTION' to go to "Share Wi-Fi" screen using "Intent"?

Answer (score 1):

**com.google.zxing:core ------ this library will be used, may be we can use default way but that time process will be little bit complex ..**> **Below code we can use to generate QR code depending on wifi name and password ,,, even we can use logo in the middle of qr if required
**

/**
*This class can be used as common class to generate any qr ..
**/

object QrUtils {

```
/**
 * generate wifi qr with this method ..
 * @param ssid is the exact name of network to generate qr ..
 * @param encryption is the network type encryption
 * @param password is the network pass
 * @param middleLogoBitmap is anything you want to set
 * @param context the fragmentContext ..
 * @param isShowMiddleIcon default true ---  to set icon ... can set false if required ..
 * @return [Bitmap] is the final result of QR to show
 */

fun generateWifiQrCode(ssid: String,
                       encryption : String,
                       password:String ,
                       middleLogoBitmap: Bitmap?,
                       context: Context , isShowMiddleIcon : Boolean? = true
): Bitmap {
    val logoBitmap =  middleLogoBitmap ?: getDefaultBitmap(context)
    val size = 1024 //pixels
    val qrCodeContent = "WIFI:S:$ssid;T:$encryption;P:$password;;"
    val hints = hashMapOf<EncodeHintType, Int>().also {
        it[EncodeHintType.MARGIN] = 0

    }
    // Make the QR code buffer border narrower
    val bits = QRCodeWriter()
        .encode(qrCodeContent, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size,hints)
    val qrBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).also {
        for (x in 0 until size) {
            for (y in 0 until size) {
                it.setPixel(x, y, if (bits[x, y]) Color.BLACK else Color.WHITE)
            }
        }
    }
    // no icon ..
    if(isShowMiddleIcon == false){
        return  qrBitmap
    }

    // something wrong to found default ..
    if(logoBitmap == null){
        return  qrBitmap
    }

    // custom or default icon will set ..
    return generateQrWithLogo(qrBitmap,logoBitmap)
}


/**
 * This method will generating qr with logo
 * @param qrcode is the exact bitmap of data
 * @param bitmap is the logo to set in middle ..
 * @return [Bitmap] is the final result of updated QR to show ..
 */
private fun generateQrWithLogo(qrcode: Bitmap, bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val combined =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(qrcode.width, qrcode.height, qrcode.config)
    val canvas = Canvas(combined)
    val canvasWidth = canvas.width
    val canvasHeight = canvas.height
    canvas.drawBitmap(qrcode, Matrix(), null)

    val resizeLogo =
        bitmap.let { Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(it, canvasWidth / 5, canvasHeight / 5, true) }
    val centreX = (canvasWidth - resizeLogo.width) / 2
    val centreY = (canvasHeight - resizeLogo.height) / 2
    val targetBmp: Bitmap = resizeLogo.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false)
    canvas.drawBitmap(targetBmp, centreX.toFloat(), centreY.toFloat(), null)
    return combined
}


/**
 * GET DEFAULT BITMAP ...  IF ANY
 * given drawable -- R.drawable.ic_default_beeda_placeholder_qr --- can be replaced
 * @param mContext
 * @return [Bitmap] is the default bitmap to show ..
 */

@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
private fun getDefaultBitmap(mContext : Context): Bitmap? {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_default_beeda_placeholder_qr)!!
    return try {
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            drawable.intrinsicWidth,
            drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        bitmap
    } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
        // Handle the error
        null
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for security reasons I don't wanna touch the wifi password. My idea is just display straightforward the "Share Wi-Fi" screen from Android OS configs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the QR code screen directly, you should try showing QR Code directly in your app, you can achieve this functionality by using the following library

`com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0`

The library is used to create the QR Codes and to achieve such QR code you must have the SSID, Encryption Type and Password of the connected wifi network.

```
fun generateWifiQRCode(ssid: String, password: String, encryptionType: String): Bitmap? {
    val wifiNetwork = "WIFI:T:$encryptionType;S:$ssid;P:$password;;"
    val multiFormatWriter = MultiFormatWriter()
    
    try {
        val bitMatrix: BitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(wifiNetwork, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200)
        val barcodeEncoder = BarcodeEncoder()
        return barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for security reasons I don't wanna touch the wifi password. My idea is just display straightforward the "Share Wi-Fi" screen.